# Java System.setProperties might effect other code

Tags: java, properties, system

Recently I integrated a piece of code into existing project.
However in order for the code to work following properties have been set:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory","com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl");
System.setProperty("javax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory","com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPFactory1_1Impl");
System.setProperty("javax.xml.soap.MetaFactory","com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl");

System.setProperty("weblogic.security.SSL.enforceConstraints","off");
System.setProperty("weblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification","true");
System.setProperty("weblogic.security.SSL.strictcertchecking","false");
System.setProperty("weblogic.security.SSL.nojce","true");
```

Now everything seems to work nicely, however I have a big concern.

1) Can above properties mess up functionality elsewhere in a huge application?

2) Can I set some properties that are specific to my Object only? Meaning that I wouldn't have to set system wide properties in order to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe System will tie to the JVM running.  If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're wondering if this will affect functionality elsewhere.

It is possible to affect functionality if you load up another application that depends on the properties being set above within the same JVM.

i.e.

```
System.setProperty("weblogic.security.SSL.enforceConstraints","on");
```

being set in a different application.  The other thing to worry about is are these properties being set at deploy time, then considered immutable?  If they're accessed and changed, and other applications are accessing and changing, you'll have chaos.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Those properties are set at run-time.

Comment: Can they be changed at run time or are they treated as immutable?

Comment: They can be changed at run-time.

Comment: I'd be really wary of doing it this way then.  Especially considering I see weblogic in this property path, that tells me it's probably a web application deployed to WebLogic which is a threaded environment, so unless you're synchronizing everything (which will probably lead to deadlock, or livelock).  I'd try to engineer around having such a dependency.

Comment: I agree with you about engineering around. However I don't have much choice in the matter.

Comment: If you're stuck doing it this way, you'll have to make sure both accessing and mutating these will be thread safe.  Even then, you have the chance of getting unknown results.  Since all of these properties seem to signify state within the application, state might change midway through execution of a method that depends on the property, something I'm guessing you don't want to happen.

Comment: "...state might change midway through execution of a method that depends on the property, something I'm guessing you don't want to happen.". You are correct Dardo.